# Replace pipe character in XML with a new line using XSL

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

My test snippet of XSLT code transforms some data in XML to a PDF.

The stumbling block i face now here is that I have to read a string inside the XML and

replace the pipe '||' characters with new line (on the output pdf)

```
<Step>
     <TITLE>Measurement Result</TITLE>
     <MEAS OBJECT="REMARKS">
       <TITLE>Remarks</TITLE>
          <VALUE>Measurement completed.
             ||Findings: The battery is weak and should be replaced as soon as possible.
             || &gt;&gt; Contact helpline for more details
          </VALUE>
     </MEAS>
</Step>
```

How do i call a template, which could read this pipe characters and finally render new line on the output pdf.

Thanks in advance
VATSAG

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to work with the textnode, use "substring-before" to split the string. This example works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="VALUE">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="txt">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="txt"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($txt,'||'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="$txt"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($txt,'||')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt,'||')"/>
            <hr/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="txt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($txt,'||')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does not build wellformed xml but gives the idea. I used <hr/> to show the new line. Insert the appropriate code for your needs here.
What is happening? When the XSLT script comes to the element containing the text to be split, it calls a named template and sends the text as a parameter.
The named template checks if the parameter contains the split-marker. If not, the text is used unchanged. If it does, text before the split-marker is used and the text after is given to the named template again (recursive).

Comment: I gave some effort for an answer that works with your data, so you should either accept or tell what you think is missing. If I admit "it does not build wellformed xml" thats because I didn't wrap an xml document around it. It just fits in one.